# Best practices for naming conventions in web stack

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, naming-conventions

It's about 6-7 years that I develop in web stack (PHP, JS, HTML, CSS, MYSQL). But still confused about naming conventions. I know that it's up to developer which convention to use. I was using lower and upper camelcases mainly. I faced with problems like letter 'l' followed by upper letter 'i' and got some confusing combination like `delIlluminatti`. Decided to use underscore based combinations. But again, I'd want to know the best practices:

Here is how I use naming conventions

## Filesystem

- for file system elements I use upper camelcase (like `ModelController.php`)

## HTML & CSS

- for html id's and classes I seperate words with underscore (like `#full_name`)

## JS

- for js variables underscore
- for functions lower camelcase

## PHP

- for php variables, functions I use lower camelcase.
- for class names upper camelcase

## Database

- for database names I use upper camelcase, but for relationship tables I use underscore (like `Student_Score`)
- for database fields I use underscore and all lower letters

## Question is..

I'd want to hear from pros. am I doing wrong in somewhere?

Comment: For PHP and filenames, you can follow the PSR-2 standard. That's the recommendation for PHP.

Comment: Your call - off topic for SO

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the only matter is to be consistent. If there an understandable logic and you always follow it then it fine.
The rest is just pure preferences... There is no perfect rules. As long as everyone on the project agree to follow the same convention, then it is fine.

I tends to use only camelCase and CamelCase:
- camelCase for variable, css class, folder names, file names, ... (basically everything which does not represent a Class)
- CamelCase for class names / interfaces (and file names when the file contains a Class or an Interface)

But this is just my own preferences.